# How can I alias a binary dependent on the machine I am on

Tags: bash, centos, bash-scripting, bashrc, .bash-profile

I work on different machines, some as `centos7`, some are `centos6`, I build a binary `tmux` with a different version on each 'type' as the same version cannot runn both.

How can I tell my `.bashrc` to switch between version of `tmux` depending on what box I work on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `uname -m` will tell you what architecture you are on. For example, on my system right now:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

I might suggest putting archful binaries into `~/bin/i686` and `~/bin/x86_64`. (Or, if it's 32-bit Power or something else, whatever `uname -m` returns.) Then, in `~/.bash_profile` (which is the [right place for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path), have a line like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin/$(uname -m)
```

which will append this new arch-specific bin path to your existing path.

Or, if you want something other than the machine architecture, use a different distinguisher. For example, an easy way to tell CentOS versions is to look at the version of the `centos-release` package, with `rpm -q`, so, like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin/centos$(rpm -q --qf '%{VERSION}' centos-release)
```

which will get you either `~/bin/centos6` or `~/bin/centos7` — although there's no error handling, so on Fedora or something you'll get a nonsensical error message *right in the path*. (Maybe check for whether centos-release exists with an `if` statement before even running this.)

You can also add `--nosignatures --nodigest` to speed up this RPM command by a few hundredths of a second. Not a big deal, but since it'll happen at every new login shell, seems worth the extra typing.

Comment: There is a slight misunderstanding here, both are 64bit, it is the version of centos that differs, still +1

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, same basic concept but use a different distinguisher.